# can not get an an MQ MDB to work in Liberty

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-liberty, mq, open-liberty

I have a sample Java program that works. I try to put the same credentials / queue data into the MDB and I get 
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'QueueMgr1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'queuemgr1.....'.
Please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the QueueManager to which you are connecting.
This is happening in Open Liberty and WAS Liberty. 
this is my config

```
<resourceAdapter id="mq" location="/config/wmq.jmsra.rar" />

<jmsActivationSpec id="Messaging/MessagingEJB/MessagingMDB" authDataRef="MQCredentials" maxEndpoints="1">  

<properties.mq 
        transportType="CLIENT"
        hostName="${env.MQ_HOST}" 
        port="${env.MQ_PORT}"
        channel="${env.MQ_CHANNEL}"
        queueManager="${env.MQ_QUEUE_MANAGER}"
        destinationRef="NotificationQ"
        destinationType="javax.jms.Queue" />

</jmsActivationSpec>
<jmsQueue id="NotificationQ" jndiName="jms/StockTrader/NotificationQueue">
    <properties.mq baseQueueName="${env.MQ_QUEUE}" baseQueueManagerName="${env.MQ_QUEUE_MANAGER}" />
</jmsQueue>
```

Comment: Looks like I missed this: <authData id="MQCredentials" user="${env.MQ_ID}" password="${env.MQ_PASSWORD}" />

Comment: FYI, in newer releases you can use "${MQ_CHANNEL}" to substitute env vars as well in server config, which gives you a more flexible override scheme.  See:  https://openliberty.io/docs/ref/config/serverConfiguration.html